3366. Minimum Array Sum leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-array-sum/

You are given an integer array nums and three integers k, op1, and op2.
You can perform the following operations on nums:

Operation 1: Choose an index i and divide nums[i] by 2, rounding up to the nearest whole number. You can perform this operation at most op1 times, and not more than once per index.
Operation 2: Choose an index i and subtract k from nums[i], but only if nums[i] is greater than or equal to k. You can perform this operation at most op2 times, and not more than once per index.

Note: Both operations can be applied to the same index, but at most once each.
Return the minimum possible sum of all elements in nums after performing any number of operations.

class Solution {
public:

    int fun(int ind, vector<int>&nums, int op1,int op2, int k){

        if(ind<0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(op1<=0 and op2<=0){
            int sum =0;
            while(ind>=0){
                sum+=nums[ind];
                ind--;
            }
            return sum;
        }
        
        int x=INT_MAX,y=INT_MAX,z=INT_MAX;
        int curr=nums[ind];
        if(op2>0 and nums[ind]>=k){
            x = nums[ind]-k + fun(ind-1,nums,op1,op2-1,k);
        }
        if(op1>0){
            int temp = curr%2? curr/2 : (curr/2) +1;
            y = temp + fun(ind-1,nums, op1-1,op2,k);
        }
        if(op2>0 and curr>=k and op1>0){
            int temp1 = (curr-k)%2? (curr-k)/2: ((curr-k)/2)+1;
            int temp2 = curr %2 ? curr/2 -3: curr/2 -2;
            z = min(temp1,temp2) + fun(ind-1,nums,op1-1,op2-1,k);
        }
        
        return min({x,y,z,nums[ind]});
    }

    int minArraySum(vector<int>& nums, int k, int op1, int op2) {
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        return fun(nums.size()-1,nums,op1,op2,k);
    }
};

I wonder why above Solution is not working.

(I don't think this needs DP.)

@greybeard Correct.  Straightforward greedy algorithm will be simpler and faster.  Just find the best operation( largest value reduction ) still available and repeat until no more available.

@ravenspoint That reasoning is flawed. If you start with [9] and can use operation 1 once and operation 2 once with k=5, the most you can reduce the value with the first operation is by applying operation 2 to get to 4. But applying operation 1 after this results in 2, whereas applying operation 1, then operation 2 results in ceiling(9/2)-5=0.

@greybeard Are you suggesting that the greedy algorithm works?

@Unmitigated: I have been suggesting a non-DP algorithm may work - hammer and nail. (The one I sketched in my comment to ravenspoint's answer may work after refining "the halving boundary" - thanks for the examples.)

First, you have flipped all of your conditions for performing rounding. If curr % 2 is a non-zero value, that means it is not divisible by 2 so you need to take the ceiling or add 1 after integer division.
That means that this:
int temp = curr%2? curr/2 : (curr/2) +1;

should be this:
int temp = curr % 2 ? curr / 2 + 1 : curr / 2;

Note that this can be done more simply without casework by adding one before performing integer division by 2.
int temp = (curr + 1) / 2; // or curr + 1 >> 1

This line has the same issue with the inverted cases:
int temp1 = (curr-k)%2? (curr-k)/2: ((curr-k)/2)+1;

Next, you have correctly determined that one of the possible moves at an index is to do nothing, but you completely skip the rest of the array by only using nums[ind] as the value here:
return min({x,y,z,nums[ind]});

Instead, you would need to continue the recursion by passing on the same parameters but with the index decremented like so:
return min({ x, y, z, nums[ind] + fun(ind - 1, nums, op1, op2, k)});

On the line where you consider first applying operation 1, then operation 2, you have hard coded the values 3 and 2 to subtract when it should be + 1 - k and - k, respectively.
int temp2 = curr %2 ? curr/2 -3: curr/2 -2;

Moreover, you have neglected to check if curr is greater than or equal to k after being divided by 2; curr >= k is not a sufficient condition for this. This line could be rewritten like so:
int temp2 = curr >= 2 * k - 1 ? (curr + 1) / 2 - k : INT_MAX;

And now your code will be correct, but it will be too slow. This issue can be resolved by applying memoization to compute the result for each (ind, op1, op2) only once. There is also absolutely no need to sort the array.

Thanks for the clear cut explanation and for your patience.

I am trying to upvote but it says
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

@snehithoddula Happy to help.

@snehithoddula You'll be able to cast upvotes when you reach 15 reputation. If this solved your problem, you may consider accepting the answer (which also gives you +2 reputation).

class Solution {
public:
    long long  dp[105][105][105];
    int fun(int ind, vector<int>&nums, int op1,int op2, int k){

        if(ind<0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(op1<=0 and op2<=0){
            int sum =0;
            while(ind>=0){
                sum+=nums[ind];
                ind--;
            }
            return sum;
        }
        if(dp[op1][op2][ind]!=-1){
            return dp[op1][op2][ind];
        }
        
        int x=INT_MAX,y=INT_MAX,z=INT_MAX,a=INT_MAX;
        int curr=nums[ind];
        if(op2>0 and nums[ind]>=k){
            x = nums[ind]-k + fun(ind-1,nums,op1,op2-1,k);
        }
        if(op1>0){
            int temp = (curr+1)/2;
            y = temp + fun(ind-1,nums, op1-1,op2,k);
        }
        if(op2>0 and curr>=k and op1>0){
            int temp1 = (curr-k+1)/2;
            int temp2 = (curr+1)/2 >=k ?((curr+1)/2)-k: INT_MAX;
            z = min(temp1,temp2) + fun(ind-1,nums,op1-1,op2-1,k);
        }
        a = nums[ind]+fun(ind - 1, nums, op1, op2, k);
        return dp[op1][op2][ind]=min({x,y,z,a});
    }

    int minArraySum(vector<int>& nums, int k, int op1, int op2) {
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
        return fun(nums.size()-1,nums,op1,op2,k);
    }
};

This solution worked for me
 Thanks to @unmitigated

(Isn't this memoising rather than DP?)

@greybeard Memoization is also considered part of top down dynamic programming.

Unmitigated has done a commendable job pointing out problems with your function.
Not systematically tested (but for cases discussed here) code for an approach neither DP nor strictly greedy in response to ravenspoint:
""" leetcode problem 3366: Minimum Array Sum
    given a list nums of non-negative integers
          and three non-negative integers k, op1, and op2
    return the minimum total sum attainable using 
     (each at most once per index):
    - up to op1 halvings rounding up
    - up to op2 subtractions of k not resulting in a negative number
"""

from bisect import bisect_left


def _sum_halves(values):
    return sum(n // 2 for n in values)

def minimum_array_sum(nums, k, op1, op2):
    """ leetcode problem 3366: Minimum Array Sum
        given a list nums of non-negative integers
              and three non-negative integers k, op1, and op2
        return the minimum total sum attainable using
         (each at most once per index):
         up to op1 halvings rounding up
         up to op2 subtractions of k not resulting in a negative number
    """
    total = sum(nums)
    # no-brainers:
    if k <= 0:                 # don't subtract values not reducing sum
        op2, k = 0, 0
    if op1 <= 0 and op2 <= 0:  # no operations with any effect
        return total
    #
    min_reducible = 1 if k == 1 else 2 if 0 < op1 else k
    # (tried using partition by value and by count instead of sort -
    #  obscures what simplicity there is)
    (ascending := [v for v in nums if min_reducible <= v]).sort()
    if op2 <= 0:
        # no subtractions, but halvings needs half a brain:
        #  just halve up to op1 greatest values
        return total - _sum_halves(ascending[-op1:])
    #
    n = len(ascending)
    # partition into smaller than k, and >= k
    big = bisect_left(ascending, k)
    total -= k * min(op2, n - big)
    if op1 <= 0:
        return total
    #
    untouched = min(big+op2, n)
    # index of first value huge enough for subtraction after halving
    huge = bisect_left(ascending, 2 * k - 1, lo=big)
    halve_first = max(min(untouched, huge), n-op1)
    total -= _sum_halves(ascending[halve_first:])
    op1 -= n - halve_first
    if op1 <= 0:
        return total
    for i in range(big, untouched):
        ascending[i] -= k;
    # a merge of ascending[min(0, big - op1):big]
    #       with ascending[big:subtract_end] would do
    # and still feels clumsy because only few values may get used
    ascending = sorted(ascending[min(0, big - op1):untouched])
    return total - _sum_halves(ascending[-op1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(minimum_array_sum([26, 47, 81, 13, 14, 34, 18], k = 15, op1 = 3, op2 = 3))  # 108 (?)
    print(minimum_array_sum([2,8,3,19,3], k = 3, op1 = 1, op2 = 1))  # 23
    print(minimum_array_sum([2,4,3], k = 3, op1 = 2, op2 = 1))       #  3


# Python 3 template from https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-array-sum/
class Solution:
    def minArraySum(self, nums: List[int], k: int, op1: int, op2: int) -> int:
        return minimum_array_sum(nums, k, op1, op2)



(For the first time in years & revisited leetcode.com's Terms of Service. Once more didn't feel pressed hard enough to agree…)

If you've been to the leetcode site, there's one "infamous" test case in the comments, [205,307,317,329,469,608,624,684,851,882],k=431,op1=9,op2=4. A typical greedy implementation produces 1583 for it. The actual answer is 1582. This code returns 2560.

Thanks - found it, if with values in different order. There is a contribution from lovesbumblebees describing an approach entirely similar to above, preceding my off-handed comment to the question by 30odd hours.

(Two bugs with rev1 implementation fixed, I get the result attributed to greedy algorithms while never computing  some differences. Hmm, hm, hm , hm.)

Turns out with k odd and op1 to spare you got to account for the values between being even or odd.

Nice solution, but unfortunately it returns 105 when the answer should be 167 for nums=[243,644], k=277, op1=op2=2.

(@Unmitigated: running low on energy here, and not even up-to-date. Struggling with [1, 4, 5], 3, 2, 1 . Not giving up yet, but there are things not done yet: IDE for Python and/or C++, test frame.)

Perhaps we are putting too much time into a question that seems effectively abandoned. ;)

(I'm putting time in an O(n logn) approach for a problem the DP solution looks O(n*op1*op2) for - reasonable or not. (Up to above problem the approach was O(n)…))

The straightforward greedy example does the job.
- LOOP for ever
    - Find single operation that gives largest reduction
    - IF largest reduction == 0
         BREAK from LOOP for ever
    - Apply found operation

Here is C++ code that implements this algorithm
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>   /* time */
#include <cmath>
#include "cRunWatch.h"


struct numb
{
    int value;
    bool op1, op2;
    numb(int v)
        : value(v),
          op1(false), op2(false)
    {
    }
};

struct op1
{
    static int reduction(int i);
    static void apply(int i);
};
struct op2
{
    static int reduction(int i);
    static void apply(int i);
};

std::vector<numb> theNumbers;
int kop1, kop2;
int theK;

int op1::reduction(int i)
{
    numb& n = theNumbers[i];
    if (n.op1)
        return 0;
    if (kop1 <= 0)
        return 0;
    return n.value - ceil(n.value / 2);
}
void op1::apply(int i)
{
    numb& n = theNumbers[i];
    //std::cout << "op1 " << n.value << " -> ";
    if (n.op1)
        return;
    if (kop1 <= 0)
        return;
    n.value = ceil(n.value / 2);
    n.op1 = true;
    kop1--;
    //std::cout << n.value << "\n";
}
int op2::reduction(int i)
{
    numb& n = theNumbers[i];
    if (n.op2)
        return 0;
    if (kop2 <= 0)
        return 0;
    if (n.value < theK)
        return 0;
    return theK;
}
void op2::apply(int i)
{
    numb& n = theNumbers[i];
    //std::cout << "op2 " << n.value << " -> ";
    if (n.op2)
        return;
    if (kop2 <= 0)
        return;
    if (n.value < theK)
        return;
    n.value -= theK;
    n.op2 = true;
    kop2--;
 //    std::cout << n.value << "\n";
}

void gen1(int count)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        theNumbers.emplace_back(rand() % 100 + 1);
    }
    theK = 5;
    kop1 = count / 2;
    kop2 = count / 2;
}

void gen2()
{
    theNumbers = { 2,8,3,19,3 };
    theK = 3;
    kop1 = 1;
    kop2 = 1;
}

void solve()
{
    // keep looping until no more ops possible
    for (;;)
    {
        // find largest reduction possible with one operation
        int bestReduction = 0;
        int bestIndex = 0;
        int bestOp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < theNumbers.size(); i++)
        {
            int r = op1::reduction(i);
            if (r > bestReduction)
            {
                bestReduction = r;
                bestIndex = i;
                bestOp = 1;
            }
            r = op2::reduction(i);
            if (r > bestReduction)
            {
                bestReduction = r;
                bestIndex = i;
                bestOp = 2;
            }
        }
        // no reduction possible - break out of loop
        if (!bestReduction)
            break;

        // spply op that gives biggest reduction
        switch (bestOp)
        {
        case 1:
            op1::apply(bestIndex);
            break;
        case 2:
            op2::apply(bestIndex);
            break;
        }
    }

    // calculate sum of numbers
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto &n : theNumbers) {
        // std::cout << n.value << " ";
        sum += n.value;
    }

    std::cout << "\nMinimum sum " << sum << "\n";
}

// performance test
void performance()
{
    // start timing profiler
    raven::set::cRunWatch::Start();
    gen1(1000);
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("N=1000");
        solve();
    }

    gen1(10000);
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("N=10000");
        solve();
    }

    gen1(100000);
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("N=100000");
        solve();
    }

    // display timing profiler report
    raven::set::cRunWatch::Report();
}


main()
{
    gen2();
    solve();

    performance();

    return 0;
}


VSCODE project to build this app https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79223919
Performance test results
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        19.4494         19.4494         N=100000
       1        0.211044        0.211044        N=10000
       1        0.0035995       0.0035995       N=1000


(I needed a second take to see that "the pseudocode" does not mandate reevaluation of all reductions in each iteration.)

@greybeard  Sorry, I have no idea what your comment means.

(I thought of adding elements > k to a priority queue, halving values > 2k first, the result a candidate for op2. Handling these and values between k and 2k in increasing order next. If any op1 are left, apply in decreasing order. All of which still fits the peudocode.)

Populating the queue will be a significant cost.  I very much doubt that any advantage gained will offset the initial cost.  I suggest you code your algorithm, post it as an alternative answer, then we can compare the performance

This is incorrect. Try the sample data: nums = [2,8,3,19,3], k = 3, op1 = 1, op2 = 1. Your code produces 39 while the answer is 23.

@Unmitigated Thanks for the test.  See https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79223919/issues/1

@Unmitigated The correct answer for your test is 2 5 3 9 3 Minimum sum 22

@Unmitigated I have committed a fix ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79223919/commit/a1392c15ec9405bda3f337f8604b698d9450c802 ) and updated the code in my answer

How did you get 22? You can check the sample test cases and try submitting your solution here: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-array-sum/description/

And ultimately, the greedy algorithm is not correct. See my comment above for a clear demonstration of this.

@Kevin Greedily applying operation 1 first isn't always correct either. For nums = [6], op1 = 1, op2 = 1, k = 4, applying operation 1 will result in 3 and then operation 2 cannot be applied. But applying operation 2, then operation 1 results in (6-4)/2 = 1.

@Kevin  "Plain greedy will choose op2"  That is not what happens.  Why do you think it does?  You are just guessing, aren't you?  Please run the code yourself and watch what happens.

Your code is still outputting 22 for nums = [2,8,3,19,3], k = 3, op1 = 1, op2 = 1. This can be fixed by applying ceil to a double result instead of doing integer division first which makes ceil a no-op: ceil(n.value / 2.). Of course, using ceil is quite overkill; (n.value + 1) / 2 suffices. After that correction, it fails the second sample case, [2,4,3], k = 3, op1 = 2, op2 = 1, where the answer is 3 but the code outputs 4. I would recommend testing it by submitting here first.

"How did you get 22?" looking at "2 5 3 9 3 Minimum sum 22", something untoward happened with n.value = ceil(n.value / 2); for 19?!
